# Adding Chrome extension in Selenium / Python / Ubuntu

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, linux

I am having problems in adding extensions in Chrome before Selenium tests, using Python.

On the code side, it's pretty simple:

```
options = Options()
options.add_extension(/path/to/extension)
webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
```

The problem is in finding the path.
The folder where my extensions are stored is the following:

[image]

Even inside each folder I have no clue of the extension itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux your home-dir is `/home/username/`

So from your screenshot I would expect the path to be:

```
/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/extensions-id
```

Each directory in your screenshot is an extension. You could copy the extension to a path you do know. Just copy the directory with the right ID. You can find the ID's in the Chrome extension manager. Surf too `chrome://extensions/?id=` +id to check if it is the right one.